# How to check if a global variable exists and if not then define it as global?

Tags: python, syntax-error, global-variables, variable-declaration, python-3.9

I wish to do :

```py
if var not in globals():
     global var
     var = -1
```

or

```py
try : var
except NameError :
    global var
    var = -1
```

The problem is :

```py
global var
^
SyntaxError: name 'var' is used prior to global declaration
```

So what can be done to achieve similar effect ?

---

EDIT :

This is not at module level, but rather in a function. The variable is supposed to store a position value that the function uses and updates in it but needs to persist between calls.

I have been made aware that the above code is bad practise, and I agree, and request those agreeing to suggest alternative "good practise" methods, if possible.

---

EDIT 2 :

This question is required to help me fix [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554974/searching-reverse-seeking-a-pickled-file-values-getting-skipped).
There, the `obj_cnt` is getting reset at every call, bugging up the function that accesses objects from a pickled file by an "index" (an abstraction), as I try to avoid unnecessary seeking and reading by querying indexes in sorted order.

The above should clear up the "Why?" part.

---

EDIT 3:

I did not end up needing to do this convoluted stuff.
I [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68587680/16258242) the above question by using classes.

Nevertheless, thanks to everyone who helped me here.

Comment: This code is run at module level. Do you want to do this in a function or at the module level as you show?

Comment: @tdelaney I'm calling a function that accesses objects in a binary pickled file. To avoid excessive seeking and reading through for every access, I have ordered the access requests in order that they are in the file. But, the function that fetch's the object needs a variable persistent through calls that keeps the current object index (an abstraction used by the caller).

Comment: Why don't you just move the global statement up? In any case, I too find this dubious

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's ugly for the caller to have to define variables that the callee uses

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga then please feel free to ignore the question and answer something more worthy of your time. thanks for all the help.

Comment: It's not about being worthy of my time or not, it's about pointing out bad practices and anti-patterns.

Comment: @user426 - The `global` keyword can't be used at module level. If you are trying to do this in a function, then have your example show that. In a function, you just have to make sure that `global` is declared before the variable is used. The very top of the function perhaps.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "everything you are doing here is ugly...makes no sense" is not constructive, helpful criticism, though thanks anyways. I am interested in the code working though, and I will love to use better practise for that, but find not such alternative. If there is one, I will use it.

Comment: Using global state for this is a bad move, and the *way* you're managing that global state is another bad move on top of that. Even if you wanted to use global state, it would make more sense to just initialize `var = None` immediately after the function definition so you don't have to check whether the variable exists.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I don't see this as particularly anti-pattern-y. Its kindof a late binding. If a function wants to use a configuration, it can catch the `NameError` and use that for the initialization. Try and ask forgiveness.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica could you suggest an alternative for a position-keeping variables used only by the function but that needs to persist across function calls ? Apart from passing it as an argument, that is

Comment: Rather than using global state, it might make more sense to have a class instance with instance variables, or use a generator and `yield`, or just pass an argument (it's not clear why you don't want to do that).

Comment: @tdelaney I see mutable global state as a fairly widely recognized anti-pattern. Indeed, things like OOP, functional programming, they are all fundamentally ways of handling *global state*, either by encapsulation in objects, or via *removing it entirely*

Comment: Alternatives: 1) use an object to manage this state,  2) pass the value as an argument to the function, and return a new value to the caller.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica passing an argument is a bit ugly in terms of the caller sending variables it does not use simply so that the function uses them as storage objects, seemed odd and un-pythonic too.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - but I'm sure I could find a dozen examples in the standard library. Deferring initialization is a normal thing. Some people might use a sentinel like `var = None`, but the try-and-die approach is reasonable IMHO.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga come on. Global state is very important to keep track of and update in many, many, many programs

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - I get what you are saying, but a module is already working much like a singleton class. If a program is never intended to have multiple instances, modules and functions can be a reasonable solution. Adding classes just for the extra weight may be unreasonable sometimes.

Comment: @user426 you realize, there are *entire paradigms* that don't allow you to mutate state, correct? I am aware that there are a lot of poorly designed programs out there.

Comment: @tdelaney yeah, and I consider the singleton to be bad for this very reason - it is basically obfuscated, mutable global state.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - but not python. As an example, I've written test suites where any test is a single python module that I load and prepopulate with the goodies needed for the test. The goal was to have small fragments of python code focused on a single test. The module encapsulation worked well.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered bad practice to alter the global variables *(see [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/13552470))*, but for the sake of knowledge, you can do:

```
if 'var' not in globals():
     globals()['var'] = var
     var = -1
```

for what you're trying to do.

Comment: This does something completely wrong - it attempts to set a global variable named `var` to the current value of a local variable named `var`, then set the local `var` to `-1`, leaving the global `var` set to the old value of the local `var`.

Comment: Most likely, it will fail with an UnboundLocalError, because there will be no previous value of the local `var`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica apparently, `var` is an argument to the function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it is not

Comment: @user426 it would be really helpful if you gave a complete example of exactly what you are trying to accomplish, multiple people have already misinterpreted what you are trying to do

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Done. See `EDIT 2:`

Answer (score 0):

The `global` keyword doesn't unilaterally declare a variable name as a module level variable. It is used within a function to declare that assignments to a variable should be in the module namespace instead of the function instance namespace. The `global` keyword makes no sense at module level because the module namespace is already the place variable assignments go.

So, just leave the global out.

```
try:
    var
except NameError:
    var = 1
print(var)
```

In a function you need the global, but it needs to be before first use.

```
def foo():
    global var
    try:
        var += 1
    except NameError:
        print("making var")
        var = 1
    return var

print(foo())
print(foo())
```

Outputs

```
making var
1
2
```